# C - Copy one folder content to another

Tags: c

I need to create a C program that will copy one folder content to another.

The folder and destination will be provided by the user.

I need it to be in C 'cause I'm gonna run it on terminal.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can't you just use `cp`?  Also, it doesn't have to be written in C to run from the command line; you can also use shell or batch scripts, C++ code, Fortran, Java, etc.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Could you extend your question a bit providing this information?

Comment: Do you mean your user is savvy enough to run your program in a terminal, but cannot use `xcopy` or `cp -R`?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi I mean nothing, I just need it =)

Comment: "I need it to be in C 'cause I'm gonna run it on terminal" doesn't make any sense; you can write programs that are intended for the terminal in any language. The concept of "standard input" and "standard output" doesn't come from the C language standard; it comes from things like POSIX.

Comment: Anyway, what is your **question**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to write it in **C** because it is going to run on a terminal. **BASH** (on Unix) or **PowerShell** (on Windows) are ideal tools for what you are trying to accomplish.

If you absolutely **must** write it on **C** the answer would depend on whether you are allowed to run external processes within your **C** program or not.

If you **are** allowed to run external processes, then use [`execv`](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-man/syscall/execv.html) or one of its relatives to launch an external `cp` process to do the task for you.

If you **are not** allowed to run external processes, then you will have to write a C program to recursively copy your directory contents. That program will depend on the platform you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it need to be in C.

Are you running Gnu/Linux or Win?

If i were you i would directly use the cp binary..

Comment: The use: "cp -r /pathToYourDir"